# Is there a data annotation attribute to choose an editor template for a model property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My understanding is that the `UIHintAttribute` is used to select *display* templates. Is there a data annotation that lets me specify which *editor* template to use for that property?

Comment: It is used for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIHintAttribute` annotation used to apply both display and edit templates.

In order to use it for selecting an editor template you have to use either one of the [editor extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions_methods(v=vs.118).aspx)